# AJAX/PHP Not Working After Web Host upgrade

Tags: php, ajax, apache

My web hosting company recently upgraded to Apache 2.2.22 and PHP 5.3.13 and since then a piece of script will not work correctly. The webpage is a radio streamer and now the part that updates the track info from a text file does not display at all. The streamer is working fine and so are other third-party widgets.

Here is part of the script to display the album cover:

```
updateNowPlayingInfo = function() {
var d = new Date();
$.ajax( '/php_proxy_simple.php?url=playingnow.txt&_=' + d.getTime(), { 
    complete: function( jqXHR, textStatus) { console.log( 'RMX Player XHR completed: ' +textStatus ); },
    error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { console.log( 'RMX Player XHR error:' + textStatus + ':' + errorThrown ); },
    xhr:  (window.ActiveXObject) ?
    function() {
            try {
                return new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch(e) {}
        } :
        function() {
            return new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        }, 
    cache: true,
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'text',
    global: false, // @note was using false
    ifModified: true,
    success: function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {

        //alert( playingData );
        playingData =  data.split("\n");

        if ( playingData[2] && ! playingData[2].match( /no-image-no-ciu/ ) ) {
            //playingData[2] =  playingData[2].replace( 'SS110', 'AA280' ); // swap small image for medium
            //console.log( playingData[2] );
            playingData[2] =  playingData[2].replace( '_SL160_', '_SX200_' ); // swap small image for large
            $( "#nowplaying_album_cover img" ).attr( "src" ,  playingData[2] );
            $( "#nowplaying_album_cover").show();
            }
         else $( "#nowplaying_album_cover").attr("src" , playingData[2] );
         $( "#nowplaying_album_cover").show();
        },
    failure: function() { alert('failed to get play data') ; }
} );
```

And the php code:

```
    <?php
// PHP Proxy example for Yahoo! Web services. 
// Responds to both HTTP GET and POST requests

// Allowed hostname
define ('HOSTNAME', 'http://www.mysite.co/');

// Get the REST call path from the AJAX application
// Is it a POST or a GET?
ini_set( 'error_reporting', 0);
$path = ($_POST['url']) ? $_POST['url'] : $_GET['url'];
$url = HOSTNAME.$path.'?timestamp=' . time();

// Open the Curl session
$session = curl_init($url);

// If it's a POST, put the POST data in the body
if ($_POST['url']) {
    $postvars = '';
    while ($element = current($_POST)) {
        $postvars .= urlencode(key($_POST)).'='.urlencode($element).'&';
        next($_POST);
    }
    curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postvars);
}

// Don't return HTTP headers. Do return the contents of the call
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Make the call
$response = curl_exec($session);

// possibly include expires header to bust aggresive caching  -expires=>â€™+1sâ€™
header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8');

echo $response;
curl_close($session);

?>
```

I grabbed this from the raw log files:

"GET /playingnow.txt HTTP/1.1" 304

Not sure if that is relevant. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: So, what's it doing? How do you know it's not working?

Comment: Status 304 is not modified. Quick guess -- your Apache config is now caching *.txt files when it wasn't before. Tell Apache to stop doing that, or don't use *.txt for your URL. Look for `ExpiresByType text/plain` or similar.

Comment: Can you set `error_reporting(E_ALL);` somewhere in the script?

Comment: If it's just stopped working after the upgrade then it's doubtful it's the code that is the problem. I'd check the permissions of the files, make sure they are correct. Other than that, contact your host, find out exactly what has changed.

Comment: Download [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) open firebug run your ajax and then post output here.

Comment: +1 @ajreal, set `cache: false`. If that doesn't work, try forcing an `If-Modified-Since:` header with a date a long way in the past, like `headers: { "If-Modified-Since": "Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT" }`

Comment: I dont think Apache is now caching the .txt files because other, separate pages are successfully reading from the same .txt files, although in a different manner. The other web pages are using XMLHttpRequest instead of PHP.

Comment: Don't have a lot of experience with firebug but it is returning 'Internal server error 500' on the php file when it "GET" the text files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it, the file permission for the PHP file needed to be at 0644. Thanks.